# Prime solutions to $p^2(p^3-1) = q(q+1)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

> Solve:
> $$p^2(p^3-1)=q(q+1)$$
> where $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers.

Could someone help me with this question? I tried several things but I couldn't get it. I can show what I already did about that question, but I didn't go too far. I don't have the answers.

Comment: Hi! Yes, please show whatever you've done, and also give some context for the question, e.g., is it homework; if so, what course and topic; what you think might be relevant but you're not sure how to apply it; etc.

Comment: It occurs to me to take both primes in $\mathbb{Z}_6$, and consider the combinations knowing that the primes are of the form $6n\pm 1$

Comment: Hi! It's not homework, I'm studying number theory by myself because it's fun; this is a question from a brazilian book "Methods for solving Diophantine equations: from Pythagoras to Fermat" of Diego Marques. So I wrote down: $p^2(p-1)(p^2+p+1) = q(q+1)$ then $p|q(q+1)$ and since $gcd(q,q+1)=1$. $p$ can't divide $q$ because they are prime and the only case would be $p=q$, but it doesn't have solution. So $p|q+1$. Back to the equation $q|p^2(p-1)(p^2+p+1)$ but $q$ doesn't divide "$p^2$. So $q|(p-1)(p^2+p+1)$ but $q$ can't divide $p-1$ either, because if so $p--1>q$ and $q+1>p$, adding give $0>0$

Comment: so $q|p^2+p+1$ and $p|q+1$ but from here i dont know what to do

Comment: @EricMairene Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24p%5E2(p%5E3-1)%3Dq(q%2B1)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime&p=1), there's the AoPS thread [Prime numbers](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1328313p7146927).

Comment: @JohnOmielan Tyvm!

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers such that
$$q(q+1)=p^2(p^3-1).$$
Clearly $q>p$ so $q$ divides $p^3-1$, but does not divide $p-1$. This implies $q\equiv1\pmod{3}$ and so
$$p^2(p^3-1)\equiv q(q+1)\equiv2\pmod{3},$$
which is impossible. Hence no such primes $p$ and $q$ exist.

Comment: Can you explain the deduction that $q$ is 1 mod $3$ a bit more?

Comment: @hunter In the group $(\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$, the element $p$ has order $3$ because  $p^3\equiv1\pmod{q}$ but $p\not\equiv1\pmod{q}$. This means $q-1\equiv0\pmod{3}$.

Answer (score 2):

$p=q$ and $p^{2} = q$ are impossible, so we must have $p^{2}\mid q + 1$. Let $q + 1 = kp^{2}$ for some $k > 0$. Note that $q(q+1)=kp^{2}(kp^{2}-1)=k^{2}p^{4}-kp^{2}\equiv -kp^{2}\pmod{p^{4}}$. However, $p^{2}(p^{3}-1)\equiv -p^{2}\pmod{p^{4}}$, so $k\equiv 1\pmod{p^{2}}$.

$k=1$ has no solutions, so $k\geq p^{2} + 1$. Then, $q = kp^{2} - 1\geq p^{4}+p^{2} - 1$. However, because $q\neq p, p^{2}$ we must have $q\mid p^{3}-1$, so $q\leq p^{3}-1$, contradiction because $p\geq 1$. Thus, there are no solutions.

Comment: $kp^2\equiv p^2~(\text{mod }p^4)$ does not necessarily imply $k\equiv 1 ~(\text{mod }p^4)$. But it does imply that $k=1+p^s$, for some $s\ge 2$. Also, you wrote $q+1=kp^2$ at the beginning and $q=kp^2$ at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was missing the final conclusion

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I believe the proof still works.

Comment: ShyamalSayak, you're right but $p|q+1$ thus $p^2(p^3-1)=kp(kp-1)$ and $p|k$ which implies that $k=p$ but $q=(p-1)(p+1)$ and it's composite for $p>2$

Comment: Essentially, yes. I think it would be nice if you could edit your answer.

Comment: This logic is equivalent to proving $4p^5-4p^2+1$ can never be a perfect square for a prime $p$? (i.e. solving for $q$ using the quadratic formula)

Comment: Snared, i think so, because $4p^5-4p^2+1=(2q+1)^2$

Answer (score 2):

We are given that $p$ and $q$ are prime, with
$$p^2(p^3-1)=q(q+1).\qquad(1)$$
First note that $2^2(2^3-1)=28$ cannot be factorized in the form $q(q+1)$. Hence $p\geqslant3$. Also observe that $q\neq p\,$; otherwise eqn $1$ becomes $p^2(p^3-1)=p(p+1)$ and so $p(p^3-2)=1\,$: a falsehood since $p>2$. It follows that $p^2$ and $q$ are coprime. Therefore $q$ divides $p^3-1=(p-1)(p^2+p+1)$. Now $q$ cannot divide $p-1$, because then $q\leqslant p-1$, and this would give $p^2(p^3-1)\leqslant (p-1)p$ and so $p(p^2+p+1)\leqslant 1$: an impossibility. Consequently $q$ divides $p^2+p+1$. It follows that $$q\leqslant p^2+p+1.$$
From this inequality and eqn $1$, dividing out the factor $p^2+p+1$ gives $p^2(p-1)\leqslant p^2+p+2$, which may be written
$$(p-3)^3+7(p-3)^2+14(p-3)+4\leqslant0.$$
But this must be false, since $p\geqslant3$. Hence the given equation has no solution.